# Show returns from textarea on output from mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, textarea, stripslashes

All,
I have a textarea that someone can type in. When I submit the form and insert in into my database I do it like this:

```
$textarea = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['textarea']);
```

When I display the output I do it like this:

```
echo stripslashes($textarea);
```

However when I do it this way it removes the returns from the textarea. When I try and edit the textarea from mySQL though it puts the returns back in. Any idea why this would be?

Comment: by returns do you mean newlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nl2br` in this way:

```
echo nl2br($textarea);
```

If you need more info, this is the official documentation page: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php).